# Add Relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to add a foreign key into an existing table, this is what I have so far:

```
ALTER TABLE     INVOICE_ITEM 
ADD CONSTRAINT  Invoice_ItemFK  FOREIGN KEY (ProdID);
```

I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Any clue how to circumvent this?

Comment: please edit your original question - include the full definition for both the PROD and INVOICE_ITEM tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the REFERENCES clause. I have guessed at reference here - but you get the idea. The actual issue was the name of the Foreign Key. It should start with FK_.

```
ALTER TABLE INVOICE_ITEM 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Invoice_Item 
FOREIGN KEY (ProdID)
REFERENCES Prod(ProdID);
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, I tried what you suggested and received another error, here is the code along with the error:

Comment: ALTER TABLE INVOICE_ITEM 
ADD CONSTRAINT Invoice_ItemFK 
FOREIGN KEY (ProdID)
REFERENCES PROD(ProdID)

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Item'.

Comment: ProdID is a column and the primary key for the prod table, trying to add as a foreign key to the invoice_item table. Sorry if I am not being very concise with my questions, really new to SQL Server

Comment: Adding the constraint to the INVOICE_ITEM table

Comment: INVOICE_ITEM with underscore

Comment: Yes, in the both the INVOICE_ITEM and PROD tables

Comment: ok, I think the issue might actually be the name of the foreign key. I have changed it to start with FK_

Answer (score 0):

You need a REFERENCES clause to list which table you want the foreign key to point to.  For example, assuming ProdID is the primary key of the PRODUCTS table:

```
ALTER TABLE INVOICE_ITEM 
ADD CONSTRAINT Invoice_ItemFK 
FOREIGN KEY (ProdID) 
REFERENCES PRODUCTS (ProdID);
```